# Handling base64 string as application/pdf for a single endpoint on API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, api-gateway

We have an API that has multiple different endpoints, as you'd expect. We have the requirement to add a new endpoint which will return an application/pdf along with the file data.

To do this, we return the following:

```
return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${filename}.pdf`,
          'Accept': 'application/pdf',
        },
        body: fileData,
        isBase64Encoded: true,
      };
```

The `isBase64Encoded` only works when a binary media type is set in the API Gateway. As detailed here:
https://medium.com/@ngchiwang/aws-api-gateway-lambda-return-binary-image-ba8faa660839

The issue we have is that by setting the binary media type to * / * (no spaces) on the API Gateway, this, in turn, affects all other endpoints on the API.

**Example** This breaks one endpoint on the OPTIONS cors check, returning an InternalServerErrorException without reason. This endpoint is just a GET with no data in the request.

Does this mean we need a separate API just for this one endpoint, or is there a way we can include this in the same APIG?

For further clarification, this is a POST that includes a small amount of JSON in the request: `{"someValue":1234}` and returns the above application/pdf content type.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  The only way I have gotten close to solving it is by switching the endpoint from a proxied lambda integration to a non proxied lambda integration. though that throws up it's own issues.

Answer (score -2):

I'm just tackling this issue and resolved it like this:

1. Send base 64 string just as normal json response and handle the pdf part on the client

```
const sendRes = (status:number, body:any) => {
  var response = { statusCode: status, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, body: JSON.stringify(body) };
  return response;
};
  return sendRes(201, {pdf:your-base64-string} );
```

2. Then on the client (Nuxt in my case):

```
 let res = await this.$store.dispatch('pdf/makePdf')

      const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${res.data.pdf}`;
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      const fileName = "your-pdf-filename.pdf";
      downloadLink.href = linkSource;
      downloadLink.download = fileName;
      downloadLink.click();
```

This open a download window and lets you save the file locally